# Por que meu modelo Endereco retorna null depois do postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Por que meu modelo **Endereco** retorna **null** depois do postback?:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Modelo:**

```
public class Paciente
{
    public Paciente()
    {
        Endereco = new List<Endereco>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int PacienteID { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Profissao { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Endereco> Endereco { get; set; }
}

public class Endereco
{
    [Key]
    public int EnderecoID { get; set; }
    public int PacienteID { get; set; }
    public string Logradouro { get; set; }
    public string NOLogradouro { get; set; }
    public virtual Paciente Paciente { get; set; }
}
```

**HTML**

```
@model  SGMed.Dominio.Entidade.Paciente
@{
    ViewBag.Title = null;
}

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Alterar", "Paciente", FormMethod.Post))
    {
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Salvar Paciente" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </p>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Dados do Paciente</legend>            
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nome)
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Nome, new { @class = "form-control", style = "min-width:100%;" })
                    </div>                           
                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        <label>Profissão</label>
                        <input type="text" id="Profissao" name="Profissao" value="@Model.Profissao" class="form-control" style="min-width:100%;" />
                    </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Dados do Endereço</legend>
                    @foreach(var item in Model.Endereco) 
                    {                   
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label>Logradouro</label>                                
                                <input type="text" id="Logradouro" name="Endereco.Logradouro" value="@item.Logradouro" class="form-control" style="min-width:100%;" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1">
                                <label>Número</label>
                                <input type="text" id="NOLogradouro" name="Endereco.NOLogradouro" value="@item.NOLogradouro" class="form-control" style="min-width:100%;" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A construção da View para editar listas e coleções é um tanto peculiar e possui algumas armadilhas. Isso por conta dos atributos `name` e `id` dos elementos vs como o MVC fará um bind com a sua `ViewModel`.

Na sua Model altere o tipo de `ICollection<>` para `IList<>`, assim você poderá acessar seus membros por um índice

```
public virtual IList<Endereco> Endereco { get; set; }
```

Agora na sua View, ao invés de utilizar o `foreach` por um `for`, fazendo a construção dos elementos da seguinte forma.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Dados do Endereço</legend>
        @for (int enderecoIndex = 0; enderecoIndex < Model.Endereco.Count; enderecoIndex++)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => @Model.Endereco[enderecoIndex].EnderecoID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => @Model.Endereco[enderecoIndex].PacienteID)
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <label>Logradouro</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Endereco[enderecoIndex].Logradouro, new { @class = "form-control", style = "min-width:100%;" })                            
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <label>Número</label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.Endereco[enderecoIndex].NOLogradouro, new { @class = "form-control", style = "min-width:100%;" })                            
                </div>
            </div>

        }
    </fieldset>
</div>
```